# Can you trigger an action when a view is created?

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to create a trigger that fires when a view is created on a user schema?

I want to create a meta data table which will hold all the views and a listing containing what they are supposed to do.  In this system  (Oracle 9.2.0.8) there is only one user who has the create view privilege so that may make it easier.

The sequence of events should be something like
view is created   trigger fires and inserts the name of the view in the table of meta data table

I could write up some package to create views using dynamic sql but that seems a bit of overkill

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use DDL triggers in Oracle.

I haven't actually done this myself, so here are some links:

- http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ddl_triggers.htm
- http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm#i2153503
- http://justoracle.blogspot.com/2006/10/ddl-triggers.html